# Java transient runtime improvements?

Tags: java, oop, memory, memory-management, field

In my project there is no saving or loading. A new object is created every login.

Therefore technically every field acts as if it were transient. But if I were to name them all transient too, i.e

```
private final Car car = new Car();
```

(even though the Object holding this field is created every login)

change to

```
private transient final Car car = new Car();
```

Will this affect my project in any positive way with regards to memory usage or speed?

Comment: transient just means it won't be serialized by the built in java serialization mechanism

Comment: `transient` is only an indication that that field should not be serialized by an `ObjectOutputStream`. It has no other effects on performance or memory usage that I'm aware of. If your objects are not `Serializable` and/or you don't use an object output stream, then setting `transient` will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think you should think of `transient` the way you do. You should think of what would need to happen **if** you ever persist the object instance containing the `car` field. That there is currently no saving or loading doesn't matter that much. By default, I'd leave out the `transient` keyword. Also a note of warning: don't *optimize prematurely*. Many optimizations will impact readability / complexity and will therefore harm maintainability of the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no impact on memory footprint by declaring a variable as transient. Transient means the fields will not be part of persistent state when you serialize an object, upon deserialization process these variables will be initialized to their default values.

[Transient Field Description from Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Members with transient modifier will not eligible for serialization.
Adding transient modifier will not do anything to performance of program.